# Outline of style I. A. i. a. 1. ...

Tags: lists, numbering

Is there an easy way to create an outline of this form?

I. Header
[tab]A. Subheader
[tab][tab]i. Item
[tab][tab][tab]a. Subitem

I found an `outlines` package that let me specify levels with `\1`, `\2`, etc. instead of `\begin{enumerate}`, and keeping that format would be really nice.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

If you can deal with the four levels provided by the `outlines` package, then you can combine it with the `enumitem` package to format the levels:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{outlines}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\setenumerate[1]{label=\Roman*.}
\setenumerate[2]{label=\Alph*.}
\setenumerate[3]{label=\roman*.}
\setenumerate[4]{label=\alph*.}
\begin{document}
\begin{outline}[enumerate]
   \1 Level 1 
      \2 Level 2
         \3 Level 3
            \4 Level 4
\end{outline}
\end{document}
```

Comment: The sample code here does not compile for me. [Edit: It was just the missing `\end{document}` at the end. You might want to insert that.]

Comment: Is there a way to get more than 4 levels? I tried adding another `setenumerate` line, but that didn't work.

Comment: @HuckleberryFebbo What exactly doesn't work? This sample code?

Comment: sorry... it works... for some reason some of my packges in a larger example are not working

Answer (score 4):

Nevermind, I figured it out:

```
\usepackage{outlines}

\renewcommand{\theenumi}{\Roman{enumi}. }
\renewcommand{\labelenumi}{\theenumi}

\renewcommand{\theenumii}{\Alph{enumii}. }
\renewcommand{\labelenumii}{\theenumii}

\renewcommand{\theenumiii}{\roman{enumiii}. }
\renewcommand{\labelenumiii}{\theenumiii}

\renewcommand{\theenumiv}{\alph{enumiv}) }
\renewcommand{\labelenumiv}{\theenumiv}

\begin{document}
```

Comment: Those definitions should work even without the `outlines` package.

Comment: They do; I just wanted `outlines` for the convenience of using the `\1` shorthand.