# Create structure / outline manually

Tags: lists, indentation

How do I create such a construct in LaTeX:

```
1 Point A 
    1.1 Point A1
    1.2 Point A2
2 Point B
    2.1 Point B1
        2.1.1 Point B1a
    ...
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: What is the specifics regarding the indentation? Level 1 (numbered `X.Y`) seems indented differently to level 2 (numbered `X.Y.Z`).

Comment: What is your question? If you mean `\section{Point A} \subsection{Point A1} \subsection{Point A2}`... you should some basic tutorial about LaTeX. Otherwise, you should make clear what you mean.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Answer (score 2):

Combining [OP's answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/197207) and [this solution](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/12282), here's a cleaner solution:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{outlines}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\setenumerate[1]{label=\arabic*}
\setenumerate[2]{label*=.\arabic*}
\setenumerate[3]{label*=.\arabic*}
\setenumerate[4]{label*=.\arabic*}
\begin{document}
\begin{outline}[enumerate]
   \1 Point A
      \2 Point A1
      \2 Point A2
         \3 ...
            \4 ...
   \1 Point B
      \2 Point B1
         \3 Point B1a
            \4 ...
\end{outline}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Neat! Though I wouldn't recommend following the example in the `outline` documentation ;-)

Answer (score 1):

solved it on my own using *{enumerate}*:

```
\begin{enumerate}
    \item Point A
    \begin{enumerate}[label*=\arabic*.]
        \item Point A1
        \item Point A2
    \end{enumerate}
    \item Point B  
    \begin{enumerate}[label*=\arabic*.]
        \item Point B
        \begin{enumerate}[label*=\arabic*.]
           \item Point B1a    
        \end{enumerate}
    \end{enumerate}
\end{enumerate}
```